# Ubuntu host with CentOS 6 as docker container, how do I access iptables?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, centos6, centos7

service iptables failed with error code below inside a CentOS 6 container with Ubuntu as host

I've read docking as container for cgroup ro somewhere. Is this the proper way to access iptables if I want to do a "service iptables restart"?

If so, is this the proper way to do it with CentOS 7 host as well?

References:
http://rhatdan.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/running-systemd-within-a-docker-container/
http://maci0.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/run-systemd-in-an-unprivileged-docker-container/

Comment: You forgot to include the error code, and your question is more on-topic in [sf] or [su].

Comment: Actually no - if OP is a developer then it belongs here.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276579/should-docker-questions-go-on-stackoverflow-or-serverfault-or-superuser

Answer (score 1):

A "Centos 6 container with Ubuntu as host" does not have an iptables service, because Ubuntu does not have an iptables service and Docker does not virtualize that aspect of the system.  So you will not be able to do `service iptables restart`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to install iptable-persistent on ubuntu and then access the centos host through the container to restart iptables.